# Android Studio 1.3 java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load cocos2dcpp: findLibrary returned null

Tags: android, android-studio, cocos2d-x

Anyone tried using android studio for cocos2dx?

I always get this error when clicking the run button on android studio

```
Couldn't load cocos2dcpp: findLibrary returned null
```

I looks like it does not linked the library,

Heres what I tried first

on the root of my Project folder, I run a command `cocos run -p android`.

It runs perfectly and generate an apk file on `Project/bin/debug/android`
I installed the apk through adb command `adb install -r Project.apk` everything work well but when I try to run the program, it crashes, and no debug error was sent.

So I tried it on android studio to debug and find what is the cause of the error. On cocos2dx v3.7 generated folder there is a folder `proj.android-studio` I opened that folder in android studio and run and then I get the error

```
findLibrary returned null
```

anyone knows how to make it work with android studio and also the debugging like breakpoints?

setup

```
linux ubuntu
android studio 1.3
ndk r10e
genymotion
```

Comment: Please look at this screenshot for debug procedure. Hope it will help you http://snag.gy/Roa8b.jpg

Comment: Nevermind guys. I hate to say but this engine is so buggy. I'll just move to another engine, really need to finish before monday, I'll just use this when its not buggy anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Android Studio doesnt support ndk, so you cant build your solution, you need to do manually on console, and then run debug on android studio to install the APK.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to explain a little further?